# How to check libpng version

Tags: imagemagick, libpng

I am using `imagemagick` and as far as I understand, it delegates handling of `png` files to `libpng` library, so I wonder how to check what `libpng` version is used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to run

```
convert -list format | grep PNG
```

or

```
identify -list format | grep PNG
```

This reports the libpng and zlib versions that are being used.

Sometimes you'll see something like

> PNG* rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.6.17,1.6.18)

which means that ImageMagick was compiled with libpng-1.6.17 and is running with a newer shared library, libpng-1.6.18.  This is harmless, unless this shows two incompatible versions, e.g., (libpng-1.2.44, 1.6.18).

On Ubuntu and other *nix platforms, you can also get useful information from

```
ldd `which convert`
```

Don't be puzzled if the latter command shows two or more instances of libpngNN; one is being used by coders/png.c to decode the PNGs and another is used within freetype, if you've installed freetype.

Answer (score 1):

You could try either of these methods:

```
convert -debug coder xc: a.png 2>&1 | grep version

  IM version     = 6.9.2-5
  Libpng version = 1.6.18
  Zlib version   = 1.2.5
```

Or, this

```
identify -list configure| grep CFLAGS

CFLAGS         -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.18/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.32.8/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.1_1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.1_1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.4/include/cairo -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.18/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.32.8/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.1_1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.1_1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.14.4/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/gdk-pixbuf/2.32.1/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/librsvg/2.40.11/include/librsvg-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.18/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/include/freetype2    -g -O2 -Wall -mtune=core2 -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
PCFLAGS        -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
```

Or, on Ubuntu

```
strace  convert xc: a.png 2>&1 | grep open | grep libpng
```

Comment: I am on default configuration of ubuntu 14.04 and the first command returns nothing and the second has no mention of `libpng`, is there a chance it's simply not installed although `imagemagick` works just fine?

Comment: Added a hack for Ubuntu... @GlennRanders-Pehrson may know something more elegant.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson That is simpler and preferable to my hacking around - please go ahead and post it yourself and you shall have my vote too! Thank you for looking in and keeping me honest :-)

Answer (score 0):

This Ruby one-liner shows only the number:

```
ruby -e 'im_formats = `convert -list format`; mdata = /(\(libpng\s)([^)]+)([)])/.match(im_formats); puts mdata[2];'
=> 1.6.34
```